# Check the number of days is right for each month

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys I currently have a sub routine that I had hoped would take the day and the month of a date. Then check to see which month it is and if the number of days is right for that month

Here is what i currently have:
Month and day are the input month and day respectively

```
        If Month = 4 Or 6 Or 9 Or 11 Then
            If (1 <= Day) AndAlso (Day <= 30) Then
                DateOkay= True
            End If
        End If


        If Month = 2 Then
            If (1 <= Day) AndAlso (Day <= 28) Then
                DateOkay = True
            End If
        End If


        If Month = 1 Or 3 Or 5 Or 7 Or 8 Or 10 Or 12 Then
            If (1 <= Day) AndAlso (Day <= 31) Then
                DateOkay = True
            End If
        End If
```

At the moment the dateOkay returns okay for any month as long as the input for days is <=31. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of Leap Year, you really need the year, too.  There is a built in function to provide that:

```
Dim numDays As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Now.Year, Now.Month)

dateOkay = (day <= numDays)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Works great

Answer (score 0):

This method let you to check the `whole date`, and it removes the neccessity to split the `whole date` in to `day`,`month`,`year`. You can try this,

```
  Dim xdate As String = "20-02-2013"
  DateOkay = if(IsDate(xdate),true,false) 'This will return true

  xdate = "30-02-2013"
  DateOkay = if(IsDate(xdate),true,false) 'This will return false
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to display a `generic validation message` to the users like `'Invalid date.!'`, you can follow this method, else if you want to display `unique message` like `'Invalid Day.!'`, then you can use `DaysInMonth` as LarsTech suggested.

Comment: Oops, sorry i had posted this answer in a hurry, just now i had seen the comment of tim below. ok, then Mr.Op how do you input the date from users.? separately[date,month,year] or as a whole date.?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that Larstech's answer is the best (assuming you're using a `DateTime` initially, not just integers for month and day, or have some other way of getting the year as well).

I'm posting an answer to explain **why** your code isn't working the way you expect.  The reason youre code is giving you problems is that you're conditional tests on `Month` are incorrect and will always return true, which means your inner IF statement executes.

```
If Month = 4 Or 6 Or 9 Or 11 Then
```

6, 9, and 11 will all evaluate to true, making the whole if check true (I believe any non-zero integer value will evaluate to true in VB.NET, but haven't been able to dig up a link to substantiate it.  Testing on my machine in VS 2012 supports that, as well as some other discussions I've seen, however).

So what is happening is that the last if block (as you have it written) for the month will always evaluate to `True`, and as long as the day is 1 to 31 `dateOkay` will evaluate to true, no matter what the actual month is.

What you should do is this:

```
If Month = 4 Or Month = 6 Or Month = 9 Or Month = 11 Then
```

This will evaluate as you expect it to, and the rest or your code will work as expected.

I would recommend using `OrElse` instead of `Or`, which will enable you to perform short-circuit evaluation similar to the `AndAlso` you used.  In other words, as soon as one of the conditional tests in the if statement using `OrElse` evaluates to true, the rest of the conditional tests will be ignored.  `AndAlso` will not evaluate any additional conditional tests once it encounters a False result.

In comparison, `And` and `Or` will evaluate all the tests, regardless of outcome.  For example, `If Month = 1 Or Month = 3 Or Month = 4 Then` will run each of the individual tests, even if `Month` is 1.

Finally, if you're not setting `dateOkay` before evaluating the date, I would set it explicitly to False before the evaluation.  Putting it altogether you'd get something like this:

```
dateOkay = False

If Month = 4 OrElse Month = 6 OrElse Month = 9 OrElse Month = 11 Then
    If (1 <= Day) AndAlso (Day <= 30) Then
        DateOkay= True
    End If
End If

If Month = 2 Then
    If (1 <= Day) AndAlso (Day <= 28) Then
        DateOkay = True
    End If
End If

If Month = 1 OrElse Month = 3 OrElse Month = 5 OrElse Month = 7 OrElse Month = 8 OrElse Month = 10 OrElse Month = 12 Then
    If (1 <= Day) AndAlso (Day <= 31) Then
        DateOkay = True
    End If
End If
```

Again, however, Larstech's answer is the best to your question " Is there a simpler way of doing this?".